# How can I find the recursive relation?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, recursion, complexity-theory

How can I find the recursive relation,that describes the cost of the Quicksort,if we want to partition the subproblems with ratio 9:1?

The algorithm of the Quicksort that I am looking is the following:

```
Quicksort(A,p,r)
      if p<r then
         q<- partition(A,p,r)
         Quicksort(A,p,q-1)
         Quicksort(A,q+1,r)
```

Answer (score 2):

Quicksort uses a randomly chosen pivot, so it's going to be hard to guarantee something close to a 9:1 ratio unless you try multiple pivots and spend linear time on each one to find out what ratio the pivot gives. However, let's assume that you use deterministic linear time order statistics generalization of linear time median finding. Then, your recursion relation is

```
T(n) = T(0.9*n) + T(0.1*n) + O(n)
```

which will still solve to O(n log n), but the hidden constant will be larger.

Comment: Hoare's original quicksort did not use randomized pivots. Original paper here: http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/5/1/10.full.pdf Randomized algorithms are a later innovation. He used the 'cocktail shaker' method to reduce the likelihood of a worst case running time.

Comment: user2566092 Could you explain me how you found this recursive relation?

Comment: @evinda Your function spends O(n) time finding the element ranked 90%, and then swapping elements so that all values greater than the 90% element are on the right of the 90% position, and all values less than the 90% element are on the left of the 90% position. So that's where the O(n) comes from. Then you recursively call your function on both subarrays, one which has size 0.9*n and one which has size 0.1*n. So that's where the T(0.9*n) + T(0.1*n) comes from. I should have mentioned that T(n) = O(1) if n <= 1.

Comment: So,when we partition the subproblems with ratio 9:1,does it mean that the element q is at the (90/100)*n position?

Comment: @user2566092 The base of the logarithmic function will be different. It will no longer be base 2, but base 10/9. I think it's important to point this out. And yes, element q will end up at the 0.9n position after partitioning.